# Exchange script. Нow to add to the end of all lines

Tags: string, powershell, exchange-server

`powershell.exe -Nologo -NonInteractive -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer mx.company.org; ". 'Set-ADServerSettings -ViewEntireForest $true; Get-Mailbox -Server mx | select -expand EmailAddresses | %{$_.SmtpAddress} > C:\temp\1.txt ; Get-DistributionGroup -DomainController 'dc.company.org' | select -expand EmailAddresses | %{$_.SmtpAddress} >> C:\temp\1.txt '""`

writes a list to 1.txt where only the column e-mail will be printed in the form

```
abc@company.ru
bac@company.ru
..
```

Now what I want to achieve is to append ' OK' to each line, so that I get the following:

```
abc@company.ru OK
bac@company.ru OK
..
```

I'm really not familiar with PowerShell, and I did not find a way to append ' OK'
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out

```
PowerShell.exe -Command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer mx.company.org; C:\temp\email-list.ps1"
```

C:\temp\email-list.ps1:

```
Set-ADServerSettings -ViewEntireForest $true; Get-Mailbox -Server mx | select -expand EmailAddresses | %{$_.SmtpAddress +" OK"} > C:\temp\1.txt ; Get-DistributionGroup -DomainController 'dc.company.org' | select -expand EmailAddresses | %{$_.SmtpAddress +" OK"} >> C:\temp\1.txt
```

Thx 2 all!